# Multiprocessing Pool workers are not executing tasks

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to execute bulk loading on Cassandra DB using Python's Multiprocessing feature. However, the worker pool does not execute the map functions and remains idle.

**Note:** I was able to execute using the same code for previous cases with medium size input i.e. 1GB ca. But this time my input data is more than 2.5GB.

**Note:** I have 4 vcores, 16GB RAM against which I am trying to execute the code.

Following is the sample code.

```
  def mp_worker(inputArg):
        cluster = Cluster(['<ip_address>'])
        session = cluster.connect()
        #execute logic

  def mp_handler(input_data, num_process):
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(num_process)
        p.map(mp_worker, input_data)
        p.close()
        p.join()   

  if __name__ == '__main__':
        # data_tables = list of variables which points to data for different tables
        # num_tables = number of tables
        mp_handler(data_tables, num_tables)
        # some other code
```

Comment: How have you verified that you don't create a pool?

Comment: How did you verify that `map()` is not executing? You are mapping to `mp_worker` and passing an element of `input_data` yet you never use it in the method as `inputArg`, why?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just updated the post again. 

My worker pool remains idle and on debugging I checked the workers are indeed spawned. But they fail to execute the mp_worker function.
@pstatix In execute logic comment I have made an assumption that it handles the inputArg part.

Comment: Again, how are you verifying that `mp_worker` methods are not executing?